# How do I convert a resource intensive self join to a faster query?

Tags: sql, duckdb

This SQL query takes 90 minutes to run in DuckDB with my million row table. I am using a self join pattern as that's the only way I have found this query to work but I am sure there must be a faster query pattern.

- The query starts with a Common Table Expression (CTE) that selects all columns from the `main.openorder_tbl` table and assigns a row number to each row based on the "Invoice Date" column.
- The main query then performs a self join on the CTE where it joins each row (`self`) with all previous rows (`other`) that belong to the same "group" and meet certain conditions related to the "Invoice Date" and "Due Date".
- The conditions for the join are:

1. The "Invoice Date" of the `self` row is more than 90 days after the "Due Date" of the `other` row.
2. The "Date Closed" of the `other` row is more than 90 days after its "Due Date".
3. The "Due Date" of the `other` row is within 200 days before the "Invoice Date" of the `self` row.

- For each `self` row, the query counts the number of `other` rows that meet these conditions.
- The result is a table that includes all columns from the `self` row and the count of `other` rows for each `self` row.
- The output is ordered by the row number of the `self` row.

This query essentially calculates a rolling count of rows in the same group that meet certain date-related conditions. The self join is necessary because I am comparing each row with all previous rows in the same group.

**Example Input Table**

| row_number | Invoice Date | Due Date | Date Closed | days | amount | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-11-21 | 2024-03-01 | 466 | 111 | B |
| 2 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-11-21 | 2023-03-01 | 100 | 111 | B |
| 3 | 2022-10-24 | 2022-11-23 | 2023-03-03 | 100 | 150 | B |
| 4 | 2022-10-31 | 2022-11-30 | 2023-03-05 | 95 | 300 | A |
| 5 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-12-10 | 2023-02-02 | 54 | 180 | A |
| 6 | 2022-11-21 | 2022-12-21 | 2023-02-04 | 45 | 220 | B |
| 7 | 2022-12-04 | 2023-01-03 | 2024-01-04 | 366 | 210 | B |
| 8 | 2022-12-19 | 2023-01-18 | 2023-01-20 | 2 | 100 | A |
| 9 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-31 | 2023-02-20 | 20 | 200 | B |
| 10 | 2023-01-22 | 2023-02-21 | 2023-06-01 | 100 | 280 | B |
| 11 | 2023-02-28 | 2023-03-30 | 2023-04-02 | 3 | 250 | A |
| 12 | 2023-05-14 | 2023-06-13 | 2023-09-01 | 80 | 21 | A |
| 13 | 2023-06-18 | 2023-07-18 | 2023-10-01 | 75 | 456 | A |
| 14 | 2023-07-02 | 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 | 0 | 320 | B |

**SQL**

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Invoice Date") AS row_number,
        "Invoice Date",
        "Due Date",
        "Date Closed",
        "days",
        "amount",
        "group"
    FROM main.openorder_tbl 
)
select
   first(
      columns(self.*)
   ),
   count(other."row_number")
from 
   cte self left join cte other 
on
   self."group" = other."group"
   and
   self."row_number" > other."row_number" 
    AND
     (self."Invoice Date" - other."Due Date") > 90
    AND 
    (other."Date Closed" - other."Due Date") > 90
    AND 
    other."Due Date" > (self."Invoice Date" -200)
    group by
   self."row_number"
order by 
   self."row_number"
```

**Output**

| first(self.row_number) | first(self."Invoice Date") | first(self."Due Date") | first(self."Date Closed") | first(self."days") | first(self.amount) | first(self."group") | count(other.row_number) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-11-21 | 2024-03-01 | 466 | 111 | B | 0 |
| 2 | 2022-10-22 | 2022-11-21 | 2023-03-01 | 100 | 111 | B | 0 |
| 3 | 2022-10-24 | 2022-11-23 | 2023-03-03 | 100 | 150 | B | 0 |
| 4 | 2022-10-31 | 2022-11-30 | 2023-03-05 | 95 | 300 | A | 0 |
| 5 | 2022-11-10 | 2022-12-10 | 2023-02-02 | 54 | 180 | A | 0 |
| 6 | 2022-11-21 | 2022-12-21 | 2023-02-04 | 45 | 220 | B | 0 |
| 7 | 2022-12-04 | 2023-01-03 | 2024-01-04 | 366 | 210 | B | 0 |
| 8 | 2022-12-19 | 2023-01-18 | 2023-01-20 | 2 | 100 | A | 0 |
| 9 | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-31 | 2023-02-20 | 20 | 200 | B | 0 |
| 10 | 2023-01-22 | 2023-02-21 | 2023-06-01 | 100 | 280 | B | 0 |
| 11 | 2023-02-28 | 2023-03-30 | 2023-04-02 | 3 | 250 | A | 0 |
| 12 | 2023-05-14 | 2023-06-13 | 2023-09-01 | 80 | 21 | A | 1 |
| 13 | 2023-06-18 | 2023-07-18 | 2023-10-01 | 75 | 456 | A | 0 |
| 14 | 2023-07-02 | 2023-08-01 | 2023-08-01 | 0 | 320 | B | 2 |

I have tried using a window function, but the problem is if I do the window function SQL won't let me use conditionals inside of it, this is of course how it's supposed to work. Maybe there's a faster way by doing a sub query with the window function or some such thing. I am not an SQL expert by any stretch. Unfortunately I am at a loss, I know I need to filter down the table as much as possible before doing the rolling count so it runs fast but not sure if there's a way to do that in this case.

Here is the Explain Analyze output from a larger table so the timings are more realistic, the column names are somewhat different but the logic is the same:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌───────────────────────────────────┐│
││    Query Profiling Information    ││
│└───────────────────────────────────┘│
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
 ---Start CTE with index 
 WITH cte
 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Invoice Date") AS "row_number",
            "Doc|PayItem",
            "Invoice Date",
            "Date Closed",
            "Due Date",
            "DaysPastDue",
            "Gross Amount",
            "ParentName"
     FROM main.df_CustLedger
    )
 ---select the first value of 
 select first(columns(self."Doc|PayItem")) as "Doc|PayItem",
        COALESCE(count(other."row_number"), 0) as "NumberOfPaidInvoices_std"
 --       COALESCE(sum(other."Gross Amount"), 0) as "TotalGrossAmtPaid_std",
 --       COALESCE(AVG(other."DaysPastDue"), 0) as "MeanDelay_std"
 from cte self
     left join cte other
         on self."ParentName" = other."ParentName"
            and self."row_number" > other."row_number"
            and (self."Invoice Date" - other."Due Date") > 90
            and (other."Date Closed" - other."Due Date") > 90
            and (other."Due Date" > (self."Invoice Date" -200))
 group by self."row_number"
 order by self."row_number"
 
┌─────────────────────────────────────┐
│┌───────────────────────────────────┐│
││        Total Time: 272.71s        ││
│└───────────────────────────────────┘│
└─────────────────────────────────────┘
┌───────────────────────────┐                             
│      RESULT_COLLECTOR     │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│             0             │                             
│          (0.00s)          │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│      EXPLAIN_ANALYZE      │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│             0             │                             
│          (0.00s)          │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│          ORDER_BY         │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│          ORDERS:          │                             
│           #3 ASC          │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│          1628109          │                             
│          (0.39s)          │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│         PROJECTION        │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│        Doc|PayItem        │                             
│        Doc|PayItem        │                             
│  NumberOfPaidInvoices_std │                             
│         row_number        │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│          1628109          │                             
│          (0.03s)          │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│       HASH_GROUP_BY       │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│             #0            │                             
│         first(#1)         │                             
│         first(#2)         │                             
│         count(#3)         │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│          1628109          │                             
│          (10.87s)         │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│         PROJECTION        │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│         row_number        │                             
│        Doc|PayItem        │                             
│        Doc|PayItem        │                             
│         row_number        │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│         119091014         │                             
│          (0.88s)          │                             
└─────────────┬─────────────┘                                                          
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐                             
│     BLOCKWISE_NL_JOIN     │                             
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │                             
│            LEFT           │                             
│  (((Invoice Date - 200) < │                             
│ Due Date) AND ((row_n...  │                             
│ row_number) AND (((Invoice│                             
│ Date - Due Date) > 90...  ├──────────────┐              
│(ParentName = ParentName)))│              │              
│             )             │              │              
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │              │              
│         119091014         │              │              
│         (962.51s)         │              │              
└─────────────┬─────────────┘              │                                           
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         PROJECTION        ││         PROJECTION        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│         row_number        ││         row_number        │
│        Doc|PayItem        ││        Doc|PayItem        │
│        Invoice Date       ││          Due Date         │
│         ParentName        ││         ParentName        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│          1628109          ││           116421          │
│          (0.00s)          ││          (0.00s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘└─────────────┬─────────────┘                             
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         PROJECTION        ││         PROJECTION        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│             #0            ││             #1            │
│             #1            ││             #2            │
│             #2            ││             #3            │
│             #3            ││             #4            │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││             #5            │
│          1628109          ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│          (0.00s)          ││           116421          │
│                           ││          (0.00s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘└─────────────┬─────────────┘                             
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│           WINDOW          ││           FILTER          │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY││((Date Closed - Due Date) >│
│   Invoice Date ASC NULLS  ││             90)           │
│            LAST)          ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││        EC: 1628109        │
│          1628109          ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│          (0.74s)          ││           116421          │
│                           ││          (0.01s)          │
└─────────────┬─────────────┘└─────────────┬─────────────┘                             
┌─────────────┴─────────────┐┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
│         SEQ_SCAN          ││         PROJECTION        │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│       df_CustLedger       ││             #0            │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││             #1            │
│        Invoice Date       ││             #2            │
│        Doc|PayItem        ││             #3            │
│         ParentName        ││             #4            │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││             #5            │
│        EC: 1628109        ││   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
│   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   ││          1628109          │
│          1628109          ││          (0.00s)          │
│          (0.09s)          ││                           │
└───────────────────────────┘└─────────────┬─────────────┘                             
                             ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
                             │           WINDOW          │
                             │   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
                             │ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY│
                             │   Invoice Date ASC NULLS  │
                             │            LAST)          │
                             │   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
                             │          1628109          │
                             │          (1.82s)          │
                             └─────────────┬─────────────┘                             
                             ┌─────────────┴─────────────┐
                             │         SEQ_SCAN          │
                             │   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
                             │       df_CustLedger       │
                             │   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
                             │        Invoice Date       │
                             │        Doc|PayItem        │
                             │        Date Closed        │
                             │          Due Date         │
                             │         ParentName        │
                             │   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
                             │        EC: 1628109        │
                             │   ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─   │
                             │          1628109          │
                             │          (0.14s)          │
                             └───────────────────────────┘
```

I welcome any ideas to optimize the query.

Comment: Hi. Your SQL query is pretty dense. Can you share with us the idea behind the query? Or the problem that your query solves maybe?

Comment: Have you tried putting the date comparisons first for the `on` condition? i.e. ordering them from least -> greatest likelihood so that it can "break early": `invoice AND closed AND due and "group" and "row_number"`

Comment: @Christian I added an explanation for the query

Comment: Can we see your table definition, and most importantly, your indexes, and output of `explain analyze` (or their equivalents to show us the query plan), please?

Comment: Could you replace the row number with invoice date? Then there's no need for the CTE.

Comment: @Schwern I put the explain analyze into the post.

Comment: @jqurious This is 99% your query so thanks again for your earlier help. Yes organizing the date logic as you mentioned is helping a lot. 40% gain just by moving one of the date queries to the beginning of the ON condition. I was assuming that the query planner would take care of this but I guess it's not that sophisticated.

Comment: @Schwern I see what you mean I could drop the CTE and then do a join on invoice but I would be worried about duplicate invoice dates , each row is unique not by invoice date but by a separate unique key representing an invoice number and the row number ensures we can get do that little shift between the tables (self."row_number" > other."row_number") which I don't think I could do with the our invoice numbers (they're strings).

Comment: it may be useful to write in the conditions ``AND
 other."Due Date"<(other."Date Closed" - 90) 
AND
 other."Due Date" between (self."Invoice Date" - 200+1) and (self."Invoice Date" -90-1)``

Comment: @ValNik it ran fast but generated incorrect results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing it as a [Correlated Subquery](https://duckdb.org/docs/sql/expressions/subqueries.html#correlated-subqueries) maxes out all my CPU cores at 100%.

It executes ~10x faster than the self-join approach. (for a 100_000 row sample)

```py
duckdb.sql("""
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY "Invoice Date") AS row_number,
        "Invoice Date",
        "Due Date",
        "Date Closed",
        "days",
        "amount",
        "group"
    FROM main.openorder_tbl
)
from cte other
select
   *,
   (
       from cte select count(*)
       where
          cte."Due Date" > (other."Invoice Date" - '200 days'::interval)
          and
          (cte."Date Closed" - cte."Due Date") > '90 days'::interval
          and
          (other."Invoice Date" - cte."Due Date") > '90 days'::interval
          and
          cte."group" = other."group"
          and
          other."row_number" > cte."row_number" 
   ) as count
order by row_number
""")
```

```py
┌────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ row_number │    Invoice Date     │      Due Date       │     Date Closed     │ days  │ amount │  group  │ count │
│   int64    │      timestamp      │      timestamp      │      timestamp      │ int64 │ int64  │ varchar │ int64 │
├────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼─────────────────────┼───────┼────────┼─────────┼───────┤
│          1 │ 2022-10-22 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2024-03-01 00:00:00 │   466 │    111 │ B       │     0 │
│          2 │ 2022-10-22 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-01 00:00:00 │   100 │    111 │ B       │     0 │
│          3 │ 2022-10-24 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-23 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-03 00:00:00 │   100 │    150 │ B       │     0 │
│          4 │ 2022-10-31 00:00:00 │ 2022-11-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-05 00:00:00 │    95 │    300 │ A       │     0 │
│          5 │ 2022-11-10 00:00:00 │ 2022-12-10 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-02 00:00:00 │    54 │    180 │ A       │     0 │
│          6 │ 2022-11-21 00:00:00 │ 2022-12-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-04 00:00:00 │    45 │    220 │ B       │     0 │
│          7 │ 2022-12-04 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-03 00:00:00 │ 2024-01-04 00:00:00 │   366 │    210 │ B       │     0 │
│          8 │ 2022-12-19 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-20 00:00:00 │     2 │    100 │ A       │     0 │
│          9 │ 2023-01-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-01-31 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-20 00:00:00 │    20 │    200 │ B       │     0 │
│         10 │ 2023-01-22 00:00:00 │ 2023-02-21 00:00:00 │ 2023-06-01 00:00:00 │   100 │    280 │ B       │     0 │
│         11 │ 2023-02-28 00:00:00 │ 2023-03-30 00:00:00 │ 2023-04-02 00:00:00 │     3 │    250 │ A       │     0 │
│         12 │ 2023-05-14 00:00:00 │ 2023-06-13 00:00:00 │ 2023-09-01 00:00:00 │    80 │     21 │ A       │     1 │
│         13 │ 2023-06-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-07-18 00:00:00 │ 2023-10-01 00:00:00 │    75 │    456 │ A       │     0 │
│         14 │ 2023-07-02 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │ 2023-08-01 00:00:00 │     0 │    320 │ B       │     2 │
├────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴────────┴─────────┴───────┤
│ 14 rows                                                                                               8 columns │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

#### Further Info

> In DuckDB, subqueries are always decorrelated. DuckDB uses a state-of-the-art subquery decorrelation algorithm as described in the [Unnesting Arbitrary Queries paper](https://cs.emis.de/LNI/Proceedings/Proceedings241/383.pdf). This allows all subqueries to be decorrelated and executed as a single, much more efficient, query.

- https://duckdb.org/2023/05/26/correlated-subqueries-in-sql.html#performance

Comment: I got the same result, old query took 4 minutes, your new one took 43 seconds. Thanks this is awesome!